# How do I set the value of a checkbox with mobx-form?

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

Using mobx-form I'm trying to set mark a checkbox to checked when the form loads.  Setting the value or checked properties doesn't seem to work.

```
const fields = [
  {
    name: 'my_checkbox',
    label: 'The Checkbox: ',
    type: 'checkbox',
    rules: 'boolean',
    value: true, // do I set initial, default ?
    checked:true
  },
];
```

...

```
<input {...form.$('my_checkbox').bind()} />
```

Full sample code https://codesandbox.io/s/N914WNRpv

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a checked property like this

```
<input
        checked={field.value}
        {...field.bind({
          type: 'checkbox',
        })}
      /> {field.label}
```

See: https://github.com/foxhound87/mobx-react-form-demo/blob/master/src/components/inputs/SimpleCheckbox.jsx

Answer (score 0):

The **checked={field.value}** must be after the "**bind**" function, if you want the default value working properly !!

```
<input             
    {...field.bind({
        type: 'checkbox',
    })}
    checked={field.value}
/> {field.label}
```